# How do I treat linker warnings as errors with Clang?

Tags: c++, clang, ld, linker-warning

I am using cmake.

I tried

`-fatal-warnings` (mentioned [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld))

`-fatal_warnings` (which is mentioned with `man ld`)

Are those supposed to be used with `-W`?

I would like all linker warnings across the whole project to be an error.

The warning I get is:

`ld: warning: ignoring file libvst2sdk.a, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format ( 0x21 0x3C 0x61 0x72 0x63 0x68 0x3E 0x0A 0x23 0x31 0x2F 0x32 0x30 0x20 0x20 0x20 )`

Comment: -Werror i believe

Answer (score 2):

-Werror is a compiling flag that treat warnings as errors, and it's not a linker flag.

**-Wl,--fatal-warnings**
-Wl means passing options to linker.

and here is pass 3 options to linker seperated by space:
**-Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel  -Wl,--fatal-warnings**
or seperated by comma:
**-Wl,--build-id,--warn-shared-textrel,--fatal-warnings**